# Tag text in UITextView like Facebook tags location

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, core-text, nsattributedstring, catextlayer

I have a check-in screen where an user can add comment and location. It's pretty much similar to Facebook's status update screen.

Facebook screenshot: http://d.pr/i/Mz9U

I am facing trouble in adding location name as a non-editable text in the text field (ref. Diamond District in facebook screenshot). I have tried playing around with NSMutableAttributedString but to no avail.

Using NSMutableAttributedString just helped me in adding a formatted attributedString to UITextView (and make it look like how facebook shows), *but how do i take care that the attributedString added to it is not editable but is tappable (maybe to load locations again).*

My app's screenshot: http://d.pr/i/MpUe

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: i sort of myself solved this by setting the selectedRange to desired location in textViewDidChangeSelection: